# Is it allowed to bring nuts and raisins to Colombia?

Tags: air-travel, food-and-drink, hand-luggage, colombia

I'm flying from Germany to Colombia, and I wanted to know if I'm allowed to carry nuts and/or raisins in my hand luggage. It's a small amount, mainly to have something to eat in mid-flight.

[This site](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/CO-Colombia-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm) states the following:

> vegetables, plants or plant material; meat and food products of animal
>   origin [are prohibited].

Is it safe to carry such food in my hand luggage or should I leave it at home?

Comment: If your snacks are pretzels, potato chips, dried fruit or other dry goods, you can take them in your carry-on. Snack items that are liquids or gels, like pudding, jello or yogurt, etc. may or may not be allowed depending various airport rules

Comment: I'd say, take a small amount of nuts and/or raisins for use in flight, and have some more that are of less doubtful nature (biscuits or some such) that are more likely to be allowed into the country, in case you are extra hungry.

Answer (score 5):

What you posted states clearly that you're not allowed to import such things into Colombia; however, you should have no problem taking them on the aircraft with you.  Just be sure to discard any remaining food before you clear customs and immigration in Colombia.

As noted by another poster, the usual limits on liquids/gels apply, if you're considering taking food like puddings, fruit in juice, etc.

Comment: Clearly? I interpret it differently: nuts and raisins for me are processed food (not animal-origin), so it should be allowed. Such rules are usually to contain diseases on raw material. -- note: these two items are on boundary between the two

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi "plants or plant material" - nuts and raisins are from plants, therefore prohibited.

Comment: What are "food products" that are not "of animal origin" and not plant or plant material? And your "fruit in juice" is also made partially from plant product. Note: "Plants" usually mean living plants. "Plant material" is non processed roots, flowers, seeds, wood, fruits, etc. They are usually from definition of WTO and old GATT, and so usual vocabulary in customs) and not logical definitions.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Since vegetables are also clearly prohibited, I think a broader interpretation is safer.  I don't know how Colombia is if you bring prohibited goods but declare them (here in Canada or in the US, no problem, just surrender them when asked).  If Colombia has a similar relaxed attitude, then all that is needed is to take them and declare them, and to hope for the best.  In any event, the original poster is primarily concerned with on board the aircraft, and that will be fine.